# Some time unable to set Project level Property of SoapUI through groovy code

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am fetching a value from a property file of soapui (Test step Property file) and same value along with a key I am trying to set in the Project level property of SoapUI by using a groovy code .

But here problem is that, it works some time fine and some time doesn't.
It doesn't throw any exception but it simply does not set the key and value in project level property of SoapUI .

So here is the code please look into this .

```
//Get Project 
def getProject = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project

//get the IP from property file (TestStep property file)
def IP = context.expand( '${Properties#IP}' ) 

//Set IP in Project level property of SoapUI . 
getProject.setPropertyValue( "Project_IP", "$IP")
```

Thanks 
Pritish Panda

Comment: Try `getProject.setPropertyValue( "Project_IP", IP)` without the quotes.

Comment: @Pritish Panda  try `def getProject = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getProject()` and then `getProject.setPropertyValue`

Comment: I manually deleted all the project level property and try to run the code again by doing all the modification but it unable to add property again in project level  .

Comment: @Pritish Panda show your modifications and code

Comment: Do you want a screen shot ? If you want see the code then .                                                                                                 //Get Project 
def getProject = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getProject()                                           def IP = context.expand( '${Properties#IP}' )
getProject.setPropertyValue( "Project_IP", IP)